# Issue appending data to csv

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to write a script that saves prices into a csv file, however for 2 of the inputs, it adds quotation marks when appending to the file. This is the code. When I print it off above, it does not show the quotations.

```
def insert_data(self, data):
    for p in data:
        print(p)
    with open ('tracker_file.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        writer.writerow(data)
```

This is what is append to the file

```
2021-08-26,21:57:12,"34,307.65","2,272.25",123.72,447.77
```

This is the output of the print function

```
2021-08-26
21:57:12
34,307.65
2,272.25
123.72
447.77
```

Not to sure what could be causing this.

Comment: The two pieces of data that are quoted both contain commas.  I think the quotes are present so that the commas are not construed as delimiters.

Comment: As noted, this is the expected behavior.  I'm voting to close this

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `data` variable is a list/tuple. If that's really the case, the CSV Writer will treat it as a single row. If you want every item of `data` to be a new row, it should be a list/tuples of lists/tuples:

Here's a simple example:

```
import csv

# First, let's create a CSV file
data = [
    ['2021-01-01', 10, 20],
    ['2021-01-02', 30, 40],
]

with open('file.csv', 'w') as fd:
    writer = csv.writer(fd)
    for row in data:
        writer.writerow(row)


# Now, let's append to it
new_data = [
    ['2021-01-03', 50, 60],
    ['2021-01-04', 70, 80],
]

with open('file.csv', 'a') as fd:
    writer = csv.writer(fd)
    for row in new_data:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

The contents:

```
$ cat file.csv
2021-01-01,10,20
2021-01-02,30,40
2021-01-03,50,60
2021-01-04,70,80
```

Comment: Thank you for the help turns out i was using commas in the data i was appending and the CSV library would encapsulate it with speech mars to avoid confusion. Thanks for the help though :3